# How to quickly replace many matching items with a single replacement in BASH?

Tags: bash, optimization, replace

I have a file, "items.txt" containing a list of 100,000 items which I need to remove from the file "text.txt" and replace with "111111111".

I wrote this script which works exactly as I intend:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
b=`wc -l < ./items.txt`
while read -r line
do
    a=`expr $a + 1`
    sed -i "s/$line/111111111/g" text.txt
    echo "Removed ("$a"/"$b")."
done < ./items.txt
```

This script looks at eat line in "items.txt", then uses `sed` to remove each line from "text.txt".

This script is very slow though. By my estimate, it will take more than 1 week to remove all of the items from the file on my computer. Is there a more efficient way to replace all of the items quickly?

BASH 4.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed to build a sed script to replace all the items:

```
sed 's/^/s=/;s/$/=111111111=g/' items.txt | sed -f- text.txt
```

**Update:** The following Perl script seems even faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $ITEMS, '<', 'items.txt';
my @items = <$ITEMS>;
chomp @items;
my $regex = join '|', @items;
$regex    = qr/$regex/;

open my $TEXT, '<', 'text.txt';
while (<$TEXT>) {
    s/$regex/111111111/g;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Output slows your script. Remove it and you'll notice a significant speedup.
The line to remove:

```
 echo "Removed ("$a"/"$b")."
```

Answer (score 1):

your script is slow, not only because the output (`echo "Removed ("$a"/"$b")."`).

The **main reason** is, you have

```
 sed -i "s/$line/111111111/g" text.txt
```

**in a while loop**. for example, your `items.txt` has 10k lines,  the sed line will  be executed 10k times. that is, read `text.txt` through 10k times. If your text.txt is also 10k, it is `10k * 10k`

what you can do better is, read both files only once:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a{$0="1111111"}1' items.txt text.txt
```

I didn't test, but it should work.